# yii rule manager module not access

Tags: php, yii, yii-url-manager

i wont to manage my URL like

`http ://abc.com/redmiprime`   ---> This is product details

`http ://abc.com/admin`        ---> This is module

I am trying to use this rule to access my product and module, i am not able to access my module.

but when i add any prefic on   `'<url:[\w-]+>' => 'product/details',`  rule like `'product/<url:[\w-]+>' => 'product/details',`

then i can access module

```
    'urlManager' => array(
        'urlFormat' => 'path',
        'rules' => array(
            "/" => 'site/index',
            'category/<url:[\w-]+>' => 'product/categoryProduct',

            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<url:[\w-]+>' => 'product/details',
        ), 'showScriptName' => false,
    ),
```

Comment: why  you not use any prefix in u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because in RegEx `http ://abc.com/redmiprime` and `http ://abc.com/admin` has same structure and matches first correct route (in your case `'<url:[\w-]+>' => 'product/details'`). You need some prefix or some other key url part, that tells if it's module or controler:

```
module-admin => 'module-<module:\w+>' => '<module>/default/index'
details-redmiprime => 'details-<controller:\w+>' => '<controller>/details',
```

Comment: @Designsuser By adding `'gii' => 'gii'` rules as described in docs: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/GiiModule

Comment: thnx for your quick answer and it work with this **'<module:\w+>' => '<module>/default/index',**

Comment: @Designsuser Can you access product details with rule `'<module:\w+>' => '<module>/default/index'`?

Comment: sorry my rule was **  'admin' => 'admin/default/index',  **